# How to insert javascript using innerHTML (ie6 is giving me a unknown runtime error)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

```
    var head =document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];  
            newScript = document.createElement('script');
        newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
        newScript.innerHTML = '$(window).load(function(){ someFooo(); }); ';
        head.appendChild(newScript);
```

This is causing an Unknown Runtime Error in IE6. Any other way around this?

Comment: Could somebody tell me what IE6 is?  I faintly remember somebody using it like five years ago, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 3):

Try the [`text` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534678(VS.85).aspx) instead:

```
newScript.text = '$(window).load(function(){ someFooo(); });';
```

This works in non-IE browsers as well. I've used this in FF2, FF3, FF3.5, Safari 4 (win), Opera 9+, Chrome 2, Chrome 3, and they all work.

According to the spec (I have to say this otherwise I feel misleading), you're *supposed* to use `appendChild`:

```
var script = '$(window).load(function(){ someFooo(); });';
newScript.appendChild(document.createTextNode(script));
```

But that fails in IE (`<script>` elements are not allowed to have children or some other inane IE thing). So just go with the former.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is an issue with innerHTML being used in a readonly element. This happens too when you try to set innerHTML in tbody. According to [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533897%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> (...) Doing this can also be a little
>   tricky because you cannot use
>   innerHTML to inject into the HEAD or
>   STYLE element directly. (Both of these
>   tags are READ ONLY.) The best way to
>   dynamically add styles to a page is to
>   wait for the document to load, and
>   then create the rule in a new style
>   sheet.

Why is it a readonly attribute? Here is an [explanation](http://www.ericvasilik.com/2006/07/code-karma.html).

So, you need to use a DOM approach to do this dynamic loading. Check [this link](http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html) to load external javascript resources and [this one](http://www.phpied.com/dynamic-script-and-style-elements-in-ie/) to inline scripts which is your case.

```
    newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];  
    var src = '$(window).load(function(){ someFooo(); }); ';
    newScript.text = src;
    head.appendChild(newScript);
```